# Two physics bodys moving don't collide with eachother

Tags: ios, scenekit

I want to make a two charactersNodes that those nodes will move and collide with eachother but when I use SCNTransaction, SCNAction or Animation those bodies just pass through each other and similar behaviour with moving bodies in renderer method changing position by +1.
Moving characters with applyForce is useless too.
I tried to attach dynamic, kinematic or static NodeA to other nonPhycisc NodeB and move NodeB but it also doesn't work.
I have other idea to use invisible SCNPhysicsVehicle and add to it as a child my characterNode but is seems to be too complicated.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Generally, it doesn't work well to mix physics with other forms of animation -- setting a node's position can get it out of sync with the physics simulation. If you're going to move bodies outside of physics, they must be kinematic (and then they can't be affected by collisions, only cause collisions with other bodies). Beyond that general advice, there's not much we can say without seeing a more concrete example of the problem you're running into.

Comment: thanks for replay,
Now I use setVelocity and it's quite good but how to rotate node if a can't use [heroNode setTransform: SCNMatrix4Rotate(heroNode.transform, angle - currentAngleOfHero, 0, 1, 0)]; ?

Comment: If you need to change the node's transform outside of physics, call [`resetTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNPhysicsBody/resetTransform) on the physics body. This has a performance cost, so you shouldn't plan on doing it every frame.

Comment: ok, now I understand it:)
Thanks!